# Find index of row where all the rows up until that index sum to a given number

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Cost         |    Country       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          20         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          21         |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to take the first *n* rows where the cost values have a sum smaller than 40. Hence in the case shown above I would want to create a new dataframe with only the first 2 rows. 
Is there an efficient way to do it in dataframes without iterating over each row?

Comment: Are you looking for the first `n` rows, i.e., row numbers 1 ... `n`? Or are you looking for all (disjoint) subsets consisting of any number of rows?

Comment: Yes,  I am interested in the first n rows where cost sums to 40 or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html#pandas.DataFrame.cumsum) which returns the cumulative sum of a DataFrame's or Series' elements:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cost': [12, 20, 21], 'Country': [34, 34, 34]})
cumSumOfCost = df['Cost'].cumsum()
mask_cumSumBelow40 = cumSumOfCost < 40
df_sumBelow40 = df.loc[mask_sumBelow40]
```

Comment: That works! In the second line I believe you should have  `df` not `x` after the equal sign.

Comment: @prax1telis: Uh, you're completely right. I'll correct that in a jiffy. I'm glad that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumsum() can be used to take the first n rows where the cost values have a sum smaller than 40.

df[df['Cost'].cumsum()<40]